# I cant switch between headphone and speaker

Tags: audio, headphones

I am not able to switch between headphones and  speakers .Some people have said that it has something to do with the Dell audio application, so I deleted it. However, I still have the same problem. Here are my audio settings:

I just want to switch between my notebook speaker and headphone.I dont want to plug in-off my headphone everytime.

NOTE:I use windows 10 and plug in headphone by 3,5mm jack.The speaker is own speaker of notebook.

Photos of shown devices in audio menu
[image: Image 1]

Comment: usually the headphone/speaker is seen as the same device, and you can only select one of them at a time. The change over to speakers when your headphones are unplugged is usually a physical hardware switch, so you can't do much about it

Comment: The tag [switch] is for network switches. Please read tag descriptions before you use the tag.

Comment: @Blaine My headphone was plugged when I took this screen shoot.So u say that Its impossible to switch between headphone to speaker eventhough my headphone is plugged by jack entrance ?

Comment: I assume that sound only comes out of your headphones when plugged in? If so then yes, it has automatically switched to headphones, and will go back to speakers when unplugged via the hardware switch. (Eg: speakers are hardware disabled when headphones are plugged in)

Comment: @blame
Its bad.Hmm anyway thank u Blaine.Good day.